# FB og meta data overwrites fb.ui dialog

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm having issues with sharing dynamic content on FB for a quiz i'm building. I'm using a similar method as I have in the past, but its not working this time. It appears that the og meta data is overwriting the data I want to add from the object inside the FB.ui method.

So I initiate FB in the html page and add the SDK:

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : 'app_id',
        cookie     : true,
        status     : true,
        xfbml      : true,
        oauth      : true,
        version    : 'v2.10'
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
};

(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

I then add a results sharing button:

```
<div class="social-btn" id="fb-shareBtn-results">
<i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
<span>Share</span>
</div>
```

then in my js file I have object with a method that contains the event listener I bind to the results sharing button like so:

```
 var quiz = {
    score_tracker: 0,
    facebookShare: function() {
    document.getElementById('fb-shareBtn-results').onclick = function() {
        FB.ui({
            method: 'feed',
            name: 'Quiz name',
            title: 'I scored ' + quiz.score_tracker + ', can you beat me!?',
            description: 'A fun quiz',
            link: 'http://link-to-quiz/index.html',
            picture: 'http://link-to-quiz/assets/img.png',
            link: 'http://link-to-quiz/index.html',
        }, function (response) {});
    };
},
init: function(){
    sf_quiz.facebookShare();
}}
```

When I click the share button at the end of the quiz it opens the fb share dialog but pulls in the og meta data... I'm not sure why. I have also tried building the url and adding it to the href of an a link and this doesn't work either.

If anyone has got any ideas why I would be extremely grateful!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Custom/dynamic tags are not possible anymore: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/06/27/API-Change-Log-Modifying-Link-Previews/

You have to use static URLs with Open Graph tags. Use a parameter in the URL to show different tags.

Comment: Ah, Ok, thanks for the link. This is disappointing, but I can understand the thinking. Would you mind expanding slightly on how you would use a param in the url to show different tags? I have managed to change the og tags using action_properties and JSON.stringify({object:obj}) but when the result on the users fb page is 'user shared an object..'

Comment: http://link-to-quiz/index.php?param1=customvalue - of course you need a server language to get the param1 value and show different og tags depending on that value. for example, you can put the score in the param value.

Comment: Oh I see. Im not so confident with server side languages. Thanks for the tip though!